# How to change ZOrder in a CCSequence?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite, z-order

I would like to know how to change the ZOrder of a CCSprite in a CCSequence. I have tried using CCCallBlock as suggested in another thread but it has bugged out and stops the other sprites of the same class moving. Is there another method someone can suggest?

```
crystalEntryPoint = [self position];
float xD = [crystal position].x - crystalEntryPoint.x;
float yD = [crystal position].y - crystalEntryPoint.y;
CGPoint dest = ccp(crystalEntryPoint.x + (xD * 2),crystalEntryPoint.y + (yD * 2));
float easingRate = 2;

CCMoveTo *moveTo = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:dest];
CCMoveTo *moveBack = [CCMoveTo actionWithDuration:1 position:crystalEntryPoint];
CCEaseInOut *easeTo = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:moveTo rate:easingRate];
CCEaseInOut *easeBack = [CCEaseInOut actionWithAction:moveBack rate:easingRate];
CCCallBlock *zOrderBehind = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{ [self setZOrder:kManaSpriteBehindCrystalZValue]; }];
CCCallBlock *zOrderInFront = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{ [self setZOrder:kManaSpriteZValue]; }];

CCSequence *seq = [CCSequence actions:easeTo,zOrderBehind,easeBack,zOrderInFront,nil]; //,zOrderInfront
CCRepeatForever *rep = [CCRepeatForever actionWithAction:seq];

[self runAction:rep];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `CCCallBlockN` which gives the block the node running the action as parameter. The current setup retains `self` inside the block which may cause the node not to dealloc later on because the sequence runs forever and thus holds a strong self-reference until the node deallocates - I can't say if cocos2d is able to clean it up properly, it should but it might not.

Not sure if this is related to your issue or not but it seems to me a likely explanation considering everything else in the code snippet looks fine.

```
CCCallBlockN *zOrderBehind = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode* node){ 
    [node setZOrder:kManaSpriteBehindCrystalZValue]; 
}];
CCCallBlockN *zOrderInFront = [CCCallBlockN actionWithBlock:^(CCNode* node){ 
    [node setZOrder:kManaSpriteZValue]; 
}];
```

If that doesn't work either then try `CCActionTween` which allows changing any property by name.

```
id zOrderChange = [CCActionTween actionWithDuration:0.0 
                                                key:"zOrder" 
                                               from:kManaSpriteZValue 
                                                 to:kManaSpriteZValue];
```

I'm not sure if `from` / `to` having the same value will work. If it doesn't try using 0 as the `from` parameter and perhaps even increasing `duration` to some low value like 0.01.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. Unfortunately your suggestions produce the same results. I have a feeling there might be something broken within the cocos2d framework around changing the zOrder in actions.

Comment: Have you tried setting zOrder manually? If the nodes in question have different parents, you'd actually have to change the zOrder of their parents since zOrder only affects the draw order of sibling nodes (nodes at the same level in the hierarchy).

Comment: I tried setting it manually with the same results. All the sprites are parented to a sprite batch node so i'm thinking this might be part of the issue but I have read that they maintain an internal zorder. Maybe they cant be changed as easily in an action though. To explain the wierd bug thats happening: I create an instance of a mana object and then on collion with the crystal object (both subclasses of ccsprite and added to spritebatch) it runs the actions in a loop. When the first mana object created it will be in front of the crystal and stay in front.

Comment: you can only change draw order with zOrder of sprites within the same batch node, perhaps that's the issue

Comment: When the second mana object is created it makes the first appear behind the crystal with the second in front. Very wierd but I may be asking too much of the sprite batch node. Hope that made sense as I've stayed up a bit late looking in to this :P

Comment: No same batch node unfortunately. I might just take the mana sprites out of the batch and in to a CCnode. That should simplify things.